# How to properly stop iteration in minimization in Python?

Tags: least-squares

I am posting this question because, my code is not stopping iteration at the right place. Could anyone make me sure what is wrong?

Everything is working properly (as I always think which is mistake in reality..)

**Question:**

**1)** In each iteration, I am minimizing Unfortunately, it is not minimizing correctly (very poor result). Am I stopping iteration correctly in minimization process? Any suggestions?

**Just run the following code:**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import stats
def run_iter():
    # Initial guess
    x_new = x0
    # just to pretend we have huge error
    phi0 = 1e20
    for i in range(iter_num):
         # first solution
         x_next = x_new

         # FIRST WAY
         # First assumption to stop the iteration...

         # SECOND WAY
         '''
         # Second assumption to stop the iteration
         '''
    return x_new

def example_run():

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print example_run()
```

Answer (score 4):

I see two main aspects of your problem to comment on.

**1) Convergence of the two methods.**

Your first method is convergent, but not to as high of a tolerance as you have set. Using the L1-supnorm, `np.max(np.abs(x_new1 - x_new))`, to compare the previous iteration value to the current iteration value shows that your first update mechanism converges at a tolerance of a little over 1e-14 (you can calculate the corresponding convergence level of `phi`). Your second method might not be convergent at all. The routine is being cut off by your maximum iteration bound, but even with 1000 iterations, the L1-supnorm under the second method never falls below 0.009, with iteration steps in general much smaller than under the first routine. Further, increasing the iteration bound decreases its performance. I would therefore attribute the accuracy of the second method more to your initial guess rather than algorithm performance.

**2) How to increase performance**

There are two suggestions I would give right off the bat. First, think about how you are generating your initial guess. Newton-type optimization methods are notoriously sensitive to initial conditions. I'm not sure if your current guess has any theoretical underpinnings (right now, it looks like you just picked a random value and repeated for all parameters), but if not, think about some way to inform it better (perhaps a simplified solution method - OLS is used sometimes for initial values, but you would probably have to think of something else, given that your system is underdetermined). Second, your method to deal with negative parameter values (`x_new1[x_new1<0] = 0.001`) is very ad-hoc and does not help your algorithm. If the parameters should be non-negative, you are actually solving a constrained optimization problem and that should be taken into account in your algorithm, especially in the Gradient. For theoretical details on both initial-guess sensitivity of Newton-type algorithms and constrained optimization algorithms, any good textbook on nonlinear optimization/programing should help. A good possible choice would be Boyd and Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*, which Boyd provides for free from his website [here](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf). For implementation/code, it's hard to beat [*Numerical Recipes*](http://www.nr.com/). Depending on which version you look at, it will either give you code in C++, C, or Fortran. However, you should be able to convert their algorithms to Python/NumPy fairly painlessly.

Concerning your last question about `np.linalg.norm`, I'm not sure to what part of your code you're referring.

**EDIT**

That being said, I'm not sure why you are doing any of this at all. The paper you are trying to use includes code that can be almost exactly replicated in Python. In the paper, the author is using the biconjugate gradient method, which he applies in (4.1.3) and (4.1.4) using the `bicg` function in Matlab. Rather than trying to write your own optimization routine, use the corresponding `bicg` method included in the Python module `scipy`. It can be imported with `from scipy.sparse.linalg import bicg`.

As a general note for optimization routines: if you don't have to write them yourself, don't. For the most part, there has already been someone who has spent most of their life developing efficient implementation of the method you need. Often, especially with Python, these are made freely available (with the exception of proprietary solvers). So, unless numerical methods are your thing, your time would likely be better spent figuring out the most efficient way to use those pre-written routines. In this example that would include understanding the sparsity structure the author of your paper defined in equation (4.1.2). Without that, the paper just become a matter of calculating the solution with equation (3.2.3) which you could likely do (albeit inefficiently, given that you're not using the sparsity structure) with `np.linalg.solve`. Or, since you have an underdetermined system, you could use [`scipy.optimize.nnls`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html), which also has the benefit of keeping your values non-negative. There's a nice example of its usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971165/solving-under-determined-system-of-linear-equation-in-python).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I've edited my answer to address the considerations in the paper.

Comment: Well, if you really want to use your own algorithm, I don't see anything wrong with it with respect to your Math StackExchange question. I think your best bet is to consider my suggestions in part (2). I also added two more sentences to my answer concerning how to optimize underdetermined systems with `nnls`. You could use that directly with the equation leading to (3.2.3) and avoid writing your own optimization algorithm.

Comment: That seems reasonable. Sorry, but this sounds more like a field-level conceptual question rather than a programming problem. I still think that my suggestions about including your bounds in the algorithm should help, but as for things like knowledge of `x0`, you might want to consider another forum.

Comment: As for the programming aspect of it, do you think that my answer covered the main points that could be addressed in this forum? If so, accept?

Answer (score 2):

For the FIRST stopping criterion, just use a lower error boundary than `1e20`. If you print `phi` at each iteration, you will see that setting

```
phi0 = 1e10
```

will stop the iterations at `i == 1` with a very similar result (even slightly lower).

Also, if you want more help, you should give more details about what type of optimization problem you are trying to solve, the method you're using and the ideas behind the stopping criteria.